# How to get live mobile camera feed to computer?

Tags: android, image, file, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple motion capture system. How I am doing it is I have to cameras (phones) both filming the same subject at a 90° angle from each other. And with the feed of these two cameras, I detect the wanted colors, calculate their relative 3D position and then use `blender3D` to draw a cube at that position, but it's irrelevant to my question...

Now my problem is getting the live feed from the two mobile phones to my computer to then calculate everything needed. What I am doing now, is using an app called `IP Webcam` on both phones, which sends, through the intranet the last shot of both cameras.

But the problem is loading two images over the internet 60 frames per second is very inefficient... (it works fine with very low-resolution images but I wish the images to have greater quality and detail)

Then I had an idea... I would make a mobile app that would save the last frame of the camera in a `.png` on the phone, and the computer would then access the latter. (I am not even sure it's possible :) ) I am using `Unity3d` to this because it seemed like a simple task and didn't want to learn Android studio for something this simple...

Getting the camera feed I managed to do but the problem is I can't save the image correctly. After a lot of research, I still can't figure out what to do. Where to save the image so that it is accessible to the computer? I tried saving it in the internal storage using `Application.persistantPath` and it worked (`Android/data/com.myName.productName/files/savedImage.png`), but I couldn't access it with my computer (at least I didn't manage to; no errors just it didn't load the image, maybe it's possible...). I use this code to save it :

```
Texture2D tx2d = new Texture2D(backCam.width, backCam.height); //backCam is the last shot of the back camera, type = WebCamTexture
tx2d.SetPixels(backCam.GetPixels());
tx2d.Apply();

byte[] bytes = tx2d.EncodeToJPG();
Destroy(tx2d);

string path = Application.persistantPath; //This is the problem  
File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/SavedScreen.png", bytes); //Save image
```

I then tried saving it on the SD card. But I wasn't sure what my SD card root path is, and don't know how to find it. I used this code to find it :

```
public static string GetAndroidInternalFilesDir()
{
    string[] potentialDirectories = new string[]
    {
         "/storage/sdcard0",
         "/sdcard",
         "/storage/sdcard1"
    };

    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < potentialDirectories.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(potentialDirectories[i]))
            {
                return potentialDirectories[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}

string path = GetAndroidInternalFilesDir() + "/Android/data/com.myName.ProductName/files/SavedScreen.png"
```

And I get no errors. But I can't find the saved file in either the phone's file system or through the computer...

Am I doing something wrong ? I don't know much about Android (maybe even nothing at all), so maybe I am missing something in how Android treats files? Maybe it's just straight-up impossible, so I was also wondering if you would know any way I could get the live feed (or the last shot of the camera), preferably not wirelessly?

Thank you, feel free to ask for clarification in the comments, I am really stuck here...

**Ps**: I have a Huawei Mate 10 lite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you solve the problem with storage, streaming high quality images with 60fps rate is not so trivial task. And as you don't know android development that might be even bigger problem.

I would suggest you alternative option which might help you and doesn't really require android development.

Android allows to capture screenshots and retrieve this screenshots from the device using shell:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png .
```

So you might write simple bash script which captures screenshots of a camera app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function make-screenshot {

    name=$(date).png
    name=${name// /_}

    adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/${name}
    adb pull /sdcard/${name} .
    adb shell rm /sdcard/${name}
}

while true
do
    make-screenshot
    sleep $((1 / 60))
done
```

The problem here is that transferring screenshots is relatively slow, so 60fps is hardly achievable. So another option is to record screen video and store on the device:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/screen-video.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Sorry for my late response. And what you said is what I feared. It is maybe achievable but maybe not at 60 fps, even 20 fps for me would be magical to achieve! Ill do some research on the bash screenshots! Thanks! Just one question on the topic of your last point; Is the recording saved after completion of the latter or is it possible to get it while it is recording? In other words, is the recording only stored after the completion of the recording? I don't think so myself, but its worth a shot :)